# Is there a way to get notify when mobile network is unreacheable?

Tags: notifications, mobile-network

Sometimes mobile network (cellular network) is unavailable for my phone and I won't be informed about call attempts and SMSes. Is there a way or application that notify me (by notification, vibration, sound, etc.) when mobile network is unreachable?
I'm using Android 4.1.2

EDIT: By unavailability of mobile network I mean any reason that makes that I cannot call to anyone and others cannot call to me e.g. be in out og scope of cellular network, removing SIM card or anything.

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app (free). *Trigger* > Service unavailable,  *Action > play (pre configured sound or your own choice) . constraints* None

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks but it doesn't notify me when I remove  SIM card.

Comment: Removing SIM card is not a normal action in regular phone usage, so i doubt if you can find an app to that- maybe Tasker can

Comment: @beeshyams Maybe yes but I have phone that doesn't work as should and inform me that SIM card was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I like OpenSignal, it will notify you when you leave a coverage area and also help you figure out the best service provider in your area.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal&hl=en

Comment: @Greck Did that answer work out for you?

Comment: It seems that it doesn't notify when mobile network is inaccessible due to removing a SIM card. This happens for me sometimes when my phone falls on the floor.